# Pandas create column based on index condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dataframe:

df1

[image]

2003 rows × 1 columns index column is RecordDate

df2:

[image]

(927 rows × 1 columns, index column is RecordDate)

I'd like to create a new column in df1 condition with: if df1's RecordDate and df2's RecordDate match set DailyMoneyDeposit 's value on that row otherwise set that value to zero

`df1['MoneyDeposited] = df2['MoneyDeposited']`

I can't basically do this because df1 is daily basis date in the other hand df2 only consists of day that investors deposit their money and df1's index row amount is 2003 and df2's is 927

Desired dataframe:

| RecordDate | ActiveAccounts | MoneyDeposited |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-07-05 | 1 | 9000.00 |
| 2013-07-06 | 1 | 0 |

.

.

| RecordDate | ActiveAccounts | MoneyDeposited |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-11-06 | 500 | 6190.00 |
| 2013-11-07 | 500 | 0 |

Comment: Did you try df.merge?

Comment: @JoeFerndz I tried this but didn't work ```df1.merge(d2,how='outer',on=[df.index])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how='left', left_on='RecordDate', right_on='RecordDate')
```

Comment: It worked, thanks...

Comment: can I ask you one additional question? How can I fill the NaN values with zeros?

Comment: df[col_name].fillna(0, inplace=True) or you can give for full dataframe as df.fillna(0)

Comment: No worries and @JoeFerndz suggestion should work for NaN values

Comment: @JoeFerndz thanks a lot i'm so grateful!